Demonstrating a property of a real not demonstrable.
Here's a specific question.
Can we construct a real number which we can demonstrate to be not demonstrably transcendental?
Efforts
I suspect that there is a way to construct a number directly from other things that are unsolvable and/or flirt with Hilbert's 10th problem. So we can take Matiyasevich's Theorem of $9$ unknowns or something similar. A quick description of theorem can be found on wiki. So if solutions $m_1, m_2 \dots, m_9$ are unsolvable than perhaps we cannot prove whether these are perfect squares so $\sqrt{m_1}$ is unknowable irrational or an integer. And we're closer to a statement about transcendental numbers. $2^{\sqrt{m_1}}$ is transcendental or an integer.
Another similar ansatz might be to try and connect a real number with A Gödel numbering.
Musings.
Let $\phi(x)$ be some property of reals and let $\phi(x)=1$ whenever $x\in\mathbb{R}$ has property $\phi$ and we let  $\Phi(x)=1$ whenever there exists a proof that $x$ has property $\phi$. Otherwise $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ evaluate to zero.
So we can see that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \phi(x)=1\} \subset \{ |x\in \mathbb{R}: \Phi(x)\}$.
Strangely (perhaps) enough, Neither set need be countable. Each proof needs to be finite but some proof can cover uncountably many reals.
Let $\phi$ be the property that $x$ doesn't solve any polynomials.
Then $\phi(\pi)=1 $ and $\Phi(\pi)=1$. I think it should be said that
$|\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \phi(x)=1\} \cap \{ x\in \mathbb{R} :\Phi(x)=0\}| =|\mathbb{R}|$ but there may be a problem in this. I'm unsure: We need to have some understanding of what is meant by proof. There is a problem in that a proof seems to require a finite description of $x$. But each number without finite description is clearly transcendental. The algebraic numbers are a subset of the numbers with finite descriptions. So this means if we are "given" some $x$ between say $\pi$ and $\pi^2$ that otherwise lacks finite description then we can prove it isn't transcendental.
So perhaps we need to decide if $$\Psi(x)=: \cases{ 0 \mbox{ whenever $x$ has no finite description or no proof that it has property $\phi$} \\  1 \mbox{ otherwise.}\\}$$ is actually the same as $\Phi$ (they're different objects. They might just evaluate to the same value whenever $\Psi$ halts).  I think $\Psi$ speaks to the solvability in the sense of this post. Certainly an algorithm cannot halt if it has to parse an infinite description of a real number.
$\Psi$ and $\Phi$ are different objects in that $\Psi$ also requires a description of the number. The algorithm has to take in some input. $\Phi$ is a function which only needs a real number. But we might be able to make statements about how $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ relate.
Unsure if this helpful but it might speak to my understanding/naïveté on the subject.
More questions
It seemed feasible such a number is contrivable but I was curious if one can construct a more organic/natural real number. After exploring the Lemniscate for a bit I decided that the surface areas of quartics may all be transcendental but they might not all have demonstrations of this. Statements in this direction might non constructive.
There exists a set $X$ such that $\exists x\in X$ such that there is no proof that $x\notin Y$. But it would be amazing to see a specific construction.
Motivations.
It's interesting to me to discuss the 'accessibility' of the real numbers. It's a cute form of accessibility to be able to demonstrate something not demonstrable. It makes the number more accessible then most reals. Most reals we shouldn't be able to say a whole lot about.
This curiosity has nothing to do with transcendental number theory but it's nice to have example of this because it's something discussed by undergraduates and is fairly understandable.

As always with these questions, this depends entirely on what you would accept as "construct". Even then the answer is almost always yes. Let $x=0$ if CH is true and $x=e$ if CH is false. This is a perfectly valid mathematical definition, but it's probably not what you're after.

If you want a computable number, then think of a computer constantly writing out the digit $0$ until it finds a contradiction in ZFC and writes out the decimal expansion of $e$. But even then, what do you mean with "proof"? Proof from ZFC? ZFC + Con(ZFC)? Just PA?

Try a countability argument?

The problem with all of these type of questions is that they miss some very important piece: context.
Constructions require tools and demonstrations require axioms. You have not specified either one of those.
In the language $\{<\}$ and in the structure $(\Bbb R,<)$ we cannot construct any real number, since that'd suggest some sort of a definability property, and in that structure, nothing is definable. In the structure $(\Bbb R,+,\cdot,<)$ we cannot construct any transcendental number since anything definable is a root of a polynomial in integer coefficients.
So, in what sense are constructing something? Maybe we have $(\Bbb R,0,1,\Bbb N,+,\cdot,<)$, where now we can interpret Peano arithmetic, do all sort of coding and understanding? Maybe we have $\sin$ and $\cos$ in our language? Maybe we're allowed to use limits, and so we really work with $(\Bbb R,\Bbb R^\omega,\lim,\dots)$ here? Maybe we are allowed to use "anything", in which case we use any $\omega$-sequence of cardinals and ask something about their continuum function pattern?
As for demonstrations, are we to prove directly from the theory of the structure that the number we defined exists and is unique, but not be able to prove from said theory that it is transcendental? Are we allowed to use the meta-theory (i.e. the rest of the mathematical universe) to argue about it? Are we allowed to use our foundation's meta-theory? Its meta-theory?
All of these things are not specified. Many a time people get annoyed when these questions are asked. They just wanted a cool and neat example, but mathematics lives in the details, not in the gist.
For example, if we are only allowed some finite or countable language, we can only define countably many real numbers and that's it. But if we are allowed to use the entire mathematical universe, well, it is consistent that every real number is definable. Just to make a point.
So, for example, we can define the real number $r$ whose $n$th decimal is $0$ if and only if $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+1}$, and otherwise it is $3$. Is this number equal to $0$? Is this number irrational? Is it transcendental? All of these options are very open, and $\sf ZFC$ cannot determine it one way or another, since all of these options are consistent. But if we insist on working with $\sf ZFC+V=L$ as our foundational theory, then the number is provably $0$, since we can prove the Generalised Continuum Hypothesis holds.
But in any case this might not be a satisfying resolve, since it relies on information "much larger than the real numbers", and its answer may or may not be reliant on your foundational assumptions.
Maybe we can somehow encode the Halting problem, or some variant of that into a real number? But the Halting Problem can be solved, just not in a recursive way. So if you have access to more information (e.g. to all $\Sigma_1$ sets), you can tell which Turing machines halt on $0$. So maybe we can invoke some Gödelian magic? Maybe we can encode $\operatorname{Con}\sf (PA)$ or $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZFC)$ into a real number somehow? But, then again, if we are allowed to use $\sf ZFC$ to "demonstrate", questions about the consistency of Peano arithmetic will be determined. If we are allowed to use large cardinal axioms in our set theory, then questions about $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZFC)$ are determined. It is true that we can always "find a bigger fish", but we can also find an even stronger foundational theory.
At this point, and it's natural to do so, you might be getting annoyed. You might be saying something along the lines "just in the mathematical universe, the real mathematical universe!", and if you're not annoying like that, good, but I've met that response before from professional mathematicians. And here is where we conflate syntax and semantics, provability and truth. Unless you tell me exactly what the mathematical universe is, and what are the truths that are true in that universe—which as Gödel's theorem shows, you can't quite do—I am not going to be able to tell you about something that you cannot determine. Because if you're talking about a fixed mathematical universe, either you're going to give me a partial theory (e.g. $\sf ZFC$ holds) in which case I've given you examples of definitions of real numbers which you can't determine; or you're going to give me all the truths, including whether or not a certain definition results in a transcendental real number or not.

I'm unannoyed. +1.
